# docker-compose removing shared volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this LEMP stack:

```
cadvisor:
  image: google/cadvisor:latest
  container_name: lemp_cadvisor
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - "/:/rootfs:ro"
    - "/var/run:/var/run:rw"
    - "/sys:/sys:ro"
    - "/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro"    
base:
  build: ./base
  container_name: lemp_base
  volumes:
    - /home/core/server-lemp/www:/var/www:rw
phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  container_name: lemp_phpmyadmin
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/www/phpmyadmin
    - ./phpmyadmin/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:rw
ffmpeg:
  build: ./ffmpeg
  container_name: lemp_ffmpeg
  volumes_from:
    - phpmyadmin
  volumes:
    - /usr/ffmpeg
mariadb:
  build: ./mariadb
  container_name: lemp_mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=your-pwd
  volumes_from:
    - ffmpeg
  volumes:
    - /var/run/mysqld
    - /home/core/server-lemp/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - ./mariadb/etc/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro
php:
  build: ./php
  container_name: lemp_php
  volumes_from:
    - mariadb
  volumes:
    - /var/run/php-fpm
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:ro
    - ./php/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf:ro
    - ./php/etc/cron.d:/etc/cron.d:ro
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  container_name: lemp_nginx
  net: "host"
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes_from:
    - php
  volumes:
    - /var/cache/nginx
    - ./nginx/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

When I start this stack, every file will be deleted at `/home/core/server-lemp/www` on my host which is shared to `/var/www`.

In the past this didn't happened, the new command is only `net: "host"` under nginx.

This is what my docker-compose log looks like:

```
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Going to remove lemp_nginx, lemp_php, lemp_mariadb, lemp_ffmpeg, lemp_phpmyadmin, lemp_base, lemp_cadvisor
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_nginx ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_php ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_mariadb ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_ffmpeg ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_phpmyadmin ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_base ...
Jan 18 22:10:14 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: Removing lemp_cadvisor ...
--> The deletion happening somewhere here
Jan 18 22:10:16 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: [303B blob data]
Jan 18 22:10:16 core-1 docker-compose[11563]: ERROR: for lemp_mariadb  Driver overlay failed to remove root filesystem 3f35133e0814235cc4b9814606798f50d22e472d415ca814beb3443df8b89e3c: remove /var/lib/docker/overlay/3f35133e0814235cc4b9814606798f50d22e472d415ca814beb3443df8b89e3c/merged/var/www/phpmyadmin: device or resource busy
Jan 18 22:10:17 core-1 docker-compose[11579]: Creating lemp_cadvisor
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is my base Dockerfile:

```
# Lanti/lempBase
#
# VERSION               1.0.0

FROM debian:latest
MAINTAINER Istvan Lantos <info@lantosistvan.com>
LABEL Description="This image is the base of the other app images in this project" Vendor="Istvan Lantos" Version="1.0"

ENV TERM linux
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh && ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh.distrib

RUN echo -e "\
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\n\
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\n\
deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free\n\
deb-src http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free\n\
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable-updates main contrib non-free\n\
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable-updates main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade

### Start of optimizations
# https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/
RUN echo -e "\n\
*               hard    nofile            500000\n\
*               soft    nofile            500000\n\
root            hard    nofile            500000\n\
root            soft    nofile            500000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf \
    && echo -e "session required pam_limits.so" >> /etc/pam.d/common-session \
    && echo -e "fs.file-max = 2097152" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
### End of optimizations

### Start of Nginx WEBSERVER setup
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
# Modify www-data user and set UID, GID to 500
# https://muffinresearch.co.uk/linux-changing-uids-and-gids-for-user/
RUN groupmod -g 500 www-data \
    && usermod -u 500 www-data \
    #&& `find / -user 33 -exec chown -h 500 {} \;` \
    #&& `find / -group 33 -exec chgrp -h 500 {} \;` \
    && usermod -g 500 www-data \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chmod g+s /var/www
### End of Nginx WEBSERVER setup

RUN mkdir -p /root/lemp_base_volume

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Seems like you cannot daisy chain your containers to create a build order, because something happening at `mariadb` which is causing the removal of all of your static webserver files.

This is now my docker-compose file, I went back for the old solution of mine where I used to link everything to base, than share their volumes into php, NOT DAISY CHAINING THEM:

```
cadvisor:
  image: google/cadvisor:latest
  container_name: lemp_cadvisor
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - "/:/rootfs:ro"
    - "/var/run:/var/run:rw"
    - "/sys:/sys:ro"
    - "/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro"
base:
  build: ./base
  container_name: lemp_base
  volumes:
    - /root/lemp_base_volume
www:
  image: lemp_base
  container_name: lemp_www
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /home/core/server-lemp/www:/var/www:rw
phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  container_name: lemp_phpmyadmin
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/www/phpmyadmin
    - ./phpmyadmin/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:rw
ffmpeg:
  build: ./ffmpeg
  container_name: lemp_ffmpeg
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /usr/ffmpeg
mariadb:
  build: ./mariadb
  container_name: lemp_mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=your-db-pwd
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/run/mysqld
    - /home/core/server-lemp/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - ./mariadb/etc/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro
php:
  build: ./php
  container_name: lemp_php
  volumes_from:
    - www
    - phpmyadmin
    - ffmpeg
    - mariadb
  volumes:
    - /var/run/php-fpm
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:ro
    - ./php/etc/cron.d:/etc/cron.d:ro
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  container_name: lemp_nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes_from:
    - php
  volumes:
    - /var/cache/nginx
    - ./nginx/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

I created a new container called `www` which is the base image with the static webserver files shared into from the host. `base` now only need because every other image will be built from this image.

Just like in my old solution, where I used `link` to create the network, every shared volume will meet in `php` and `php`'s volume shared to `nginx`, which is on top of everything.

So:

```
links:
  - base
```

Became:

```
volumes_from:
  - base
```

To maintain the build order and make sure that `base` will be built first.

I created a bridged network for this stack with `docker-compose --x-networking --x-network-driver=bridge up`.

But looks like the cron jobs are not working, again.

**UPDATE3:**

This is what I got with rsyslog:

```
root@0687540163a3:/var/log# cat syslog
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="13" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log(/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 rsyslogd-2145: activation of module imklog failed [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[22]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*system*wpcron) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/wpcron)
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
Jan 22 14:45:04 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jan 22 14:46:01 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)
Jan 22 14:46:01 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*system*wpcron) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/wpcron)
Jan 22 14:46:01 0687540163a3 cron[23]: (*) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

This is what my wpcron file looks like:

```
*/1 *   * * *   www-data    php /var/www/domain.com/wp-cron.php >> /var/log/wp-cron.log 2>&1
```

After the first 5 minute, `/var/log/wp-cron.log` still not created.

Comment: compose/docker should never remove the content of a bind-mounted directory, so I'm wondering what's in your `build: ./base` Dockerfile. Also, is there a reason to use `net:host` for nginx? Running with `--net=host` can have nasty side-effects, e.g. restarting your computer if the container restarts

Comment: Is there a way safely share the host's networking with my docker containers? When I used the default bridged, the wordpress cron jobs didn't worked. I included the base Dockerfile.

Comment: WordPress cron is not a "real" cron, all it does, is open the /wp-cron.php URL of your website. That *should* work normally, unless there's an issue with hairpin NAT not working. If you're using custom networks, there *is* an issue currently, that disallows cross-network requests to public ports, but being worked on here; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18354

Comment: I'll try and reproduce the wp-cron issue when I'm in the office, because it should **not** be required to use `--net=host` for that. Doing so, could potentially result in a DOS if the webserver is hacked into, because it can then do nasty things.

Comment: Thinking of that; are you, perhaps, using an internal DNS for your website? WordPress of course needs a valid DNS to resolve the IP-address to connect to. If you're using an internal DNS, you may have to either add it to your daemon options, or specify it in the compose file; https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dns

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. This whole environment is in a virtual machine under Virtualbox. The host OS is CoreOS.

Comment: I tried to create an isolated overlay network with `docker network create --driver overlay isolated_lemp` command, but I got the following error message: `Error response from daemon: failed to parse pool request for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": cannot find address space GlobalDefault (most likely the backing datastore is not configured)`. ETCD2 and Fleet is active in my CoreOS.

Comment: Are you running in a multi-node setup? If not, creating an overlay network is really not needed.Overlay networks require a key/value store to be configured to the network, documentation for that can be found here; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Comment: I'm not running it, so this is the case. In a single node we really don't have other option just to use the bridge driver if we want to create a docker-compose service? Defining `net: "host"` at every container separating the containers from each other and they won't be in the same network anymore.

Comment: You can use the `--x-networking` flag to enable the new networking. It's currently an "experimental" feature, but (I think) will be the default in the next release; https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. This will automatically create a custom network for your project, and all containers are part of that project

Comment: I have an updated question. I got use of `--x-networking`. I removed the daisy chaining of the containers. But the problem that started this (wp cron jobs not working) still remains even with isolated bridge networking also. At least now my webserver files not disappears. :)

Comment: With "not working", you mean they don't get triggered, or they get triggered, but don't work? Please be aware that WordPress does not run an actual cron-job, but calls the "cron" job whenever a visitor opens the website. WordPress will then call the `http://your.website/wp-cron.php` URL. If the WordPress container is not able to resolve `http://your.website`, then that cron will fail.

Comment: `wp-cron.php` not triggered. It's the same when I turned `wp-cron.php` off in `wp-config.php` with `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` and placed a crontab file in `/etc/cron.d` dir at the name of `wpcron` with the content of `*/5 * * * * php /var/www/domain.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1` following this tutorial: https://www.lucasrolff.com/wordpress/why-wp-cron-sucks/ When I used `net: "host"` on the containers the cron job triggered at every 5 minute (I know it because it created posts from externel api source).

Comment: I created an another issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962020/cron-and-crontab-files-not-executed-in-docker Seems like within a bare minimum docker image cron jobs still not be executed. Probably the problem not because the network is bridged (although sometimes run the cron jobs in host mode, but not always, wich is strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same issue with you.I think that there are some problems with `lemp_mariadb` container.

To solve this issue. You should try the steps below:
Get `lemp_mariadb` container id:

```
docker ps -a
```

If you see `lemp_mariadb` status is `Dead`. You should go to `/var/lib/docker/containers`. You find the directory that has same name with lemp_mariadb container id and delete it

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/lemp_mariadb_container_id
```

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately I deleted everything before this method but I saw the "dead" mariadb containers multiple times. I will rebuild every image and I test again if it will come up. Overall what I did that added host networking to nginx and removed links from the images (because docker says it will be deprecated and host networking don't work with it). Do you know why is this error? What causing this? It's pretty scary that I can lost my entire webserver files if it's was in production...

Comment: did you use logrotate for docker? or made any change in /var/lid/docker/container/container_id?

Comment: Not at all. I just removed every `links` in `docker-compose.yml` plus I added `net: "host"` to all of my containers, later on I modified only to `nginx`. Every rebuild of the stack my webserver files were removed. First I thought it is the newly installed cron job feature in my php container, but when I turned off it removed again everything. Looks like with Docker 1.9, I have to create a new network that's not `bridge` or `host`, let's say `lempnet` and create a persistent storage with a new volume on the host which is at `/home/core/server-lemp/www`. Am I correct?

Comment: And I heavily need to modify my pre-installation shell script because of this (assuming I have to check on the second install that `lempnet` network already created or not, than create it, ask the user which folder he wants to create persistent storage, etc.). I know it's new mechanisms that probably serve everyone better, but I feel unnecessary over-complication again on something that worked. Pretty scary though that with production ready software you can lost all of your static files...

Comment: According to this document: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ maybe I just have to start docker-compose with `$ docker-compose --x-networking --x-network-driver=overlay up` able to get use of `net: "host"` command inside `docker-compose.yml`. I still don't know why mariadb caused to remove the volume.