# Cron and Crontab files not executed in Docker

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, docker-compose

I have this simple Dockerfile for testing, but this is also same in my LEMP stack in a PHP image: cron jobs simply not being executed in Docker.

This is my testing Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest
MAINTAINER XY <info@domain.com>
LABEL Description="Cron" Vendor="Istvan Lantos" Version="1.0"

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade \
    && apt-get -y install \
        cron \
        rsyslog \
        vim

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#cron fixes
RUN touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
#COPY etc/cron.d /etc/cron.d
COPY etc/crontab /etc/crontab
#COPY var/spool/cron/crontabs /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN chmod 600 /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
RUN touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo PID1 > /dev/null

/etc/init.d/rsyslog start

#Stay in foreground mode, don’t daemonize.
/usr/sbin/cron -f
```

And this is the Crontab file. I also placed one liners in `/etc/cron.d` or `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` with the name of the user, but the effect was the same just like if I modified this base crontab file: cron jobs not will be executed:

```
MAILTO=""
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/php7/bin:/usr/local/php7/sbin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
#17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
#25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
#47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
#52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
*/1 *   * * *   root    date >> /var/log/cron-test.log 2>&1
```

This is the output of the `/var/log/syslog` file:

```
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="14" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log(/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 rsyslogd-2145: activation of module imklog failed [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 cron[19]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 cron[19]: (*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 cron[19]: (*) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
Jan 23 09:38:39 1ab854e8d9a7 cron[19]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

`/var/log/cron-test.log` won't be created by the cron job.

I have a question for those who flagged this as "off topic" and SuperUser material, plus this is about general computing HARDWARE AND SOFTWARE: really? Docker questions when become sysadmin stuff? This way every Docker related question here have at least one flag. I'm not against promoting more users to the less known child sites, but we have more change to get the answer here than their.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I come up with until cron jobs not working:

End of Dockerfile:

```
COPY cron-jobs.sh /
RUN chmod +x /cron-jobs.sh

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo PID1 > /dev/null

# Run script in the background (this is not daemonized)
/cron-jobs.sh &

/usr/local/php7/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

cron-jobs.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  date >> /var/log/cron-test.log 2>&1
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Would the example I mentioned this morning apply here? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34960575/6309)

Comment: Did you try baseimage-docker? It has syslog and cron on board. Ubuntu though.

Comment: @VonC I tried it that example with the content of `* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1` and an empty line with `#`. Although `cron.log` created, it's not populated with `Hello World` after the first 5-7 minutes (example says it supposed to be echoing every 2 minutes?). `syslog` says `(*system*hello-cron) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/hello-cron)`. Honestly I'm happy with the bash script solution, but still good to know why not working. I would like to stick with Debian if it's possible.

Comment: `*` means every minute, `*/2` would mean at 0, 2, 4 and so on. And empty line means empty (not starting with `#`: empty)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cron (at least in Debian) does not execute crontabs with more than 1 hardlink, see [bug 647193](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=647193). As Docker uses overlays, it results with more than one link to the file, so you have to `touch` it in your startup script, so the link is severed:

```
touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*
```

Comment: I just spent 3 hours googling this issue to finally find a well explained answer and startup command to fix the entire problem. Thank you.